# Clickjacking proof under Asp.net5 MVC6?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, clickjacking

Before I always added add name="X-Frame-Options" value="DENY" or "SAMEORIGIN"
Under CustomHeaders in the Web.config but that’s gone. Any idea how to do this asp5 mvc6?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Web.config` is not gone. It has been moved from the project root to the `/wwwroot` folder. IIS still depends on these settings, including the `X-Frame-Options` setting that you mentioned, which works on all requests, not just those passed on to MVC. However, if you are not planning to host your application under IIS, you may need to find a different approach to enable these settings.

I have just tested and verified putting this section into the `/wwwroot/web.config` file adds the header on IIS express.

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="DENY" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Comment: Well, what do you do if IIS is not used then? One can run Kestrel directly or e.g. on Mac or Linux.

Comment: I would recommend finding the documentation on Kestrel (or other web server you plan to use) on how to add headers, since this is part of the web server configuration and has nothing to do with MVC or ASP.NET.

Comment: I don't think you can do it in Kestrel in some way other than middleware, unless you augment response in each action yourself :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that options depend on your environment, if you use IIS, then you can use NightOwl's answer and just fix it in web.config, this works in Azure as well since Kestrel is running behind IIS there. Otherwise I think you need to add your custom middleware that will add this header to the response (or maybe some existing middleware can do that, but I am not aware...)

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to be both compatible with IIS, and Kestrel (and thus linux) you obviously can't use config. You're going to have to go with middleware. In your middleware you would hook the `context.Response.OnStarting()` delegate inside your `Invoke() method`.

For example, the [Exception middleware](https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/blob/4e5c99fabc6afdc67a181fad2b7d20ec59ab4225/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics/ExceptionHandler/ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.cs#L70) does this, so you can copy that pattern somewhat like this (coded in comments, rather than VS)

```
public class SetHeadersMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly SetHandlersMiddlewareOptions _options;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly Func<object, Task> _setHeadersDelegate;
    private readonly DiagnosticSource _diagnosticSource;

    public SetHeadersHandlerMiddleware(
        RequestDelegate next, 
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, 
        IOptions<SetHandlersMiddlewareOptions> options,
        DiagnosticSource diagnosticSource)
    {
        _next = next;
        _options = options.Value;
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<SetHeadersMiddleware>();
        _setHeadersDelegate= MessWithHeaders;
        _diagnosticSource = diagnosticSource;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context) 
    { 
        context.Response.OnStarting(_setHeadersDelegate, context.Response);
        await _next(context);
    }

    private Task MessWithHeaders(object state) 
    { 
        var response = (HttpResponse)state; 

        // Manipulate response.Headers here

        return Task.FromResult(0); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So the accepted answer is correct if you are using IIS. If you are using Kestrel directly (Or even NGINX), then it's not going to work. And part of the beauty of .net core is cross platform!

Taken from here : http://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/01/08/set-x-frame-options-asp-net-core/

To set X-FRAME-OPTIONS or actually any other header you just need to having something similar to below in your Configure method of startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseMvc();

    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");
        await next();
    });
}
```

If you need to do it on a specific web server (e.g. Apache, NGinx etc), then just search how to add custom headers for that particular server.